# What is right way to insert onpress navigation in function which later call in render section of react native?

Tags: react-native

How to declare onPress navigation in function and I am getting undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this3.props'), what is the correct way to write navigation in function and then call that in render

```
renderItem(countrydb) {
   return <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} 
   onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('About')}>
        <View style={{marginLeft:10,marginTop:10}}>
          <Text>Name: {countrydb.item.region}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  }



render() {
    const { countrydb, loading } = this.state;
    
      return <FlatList 
          data={countrydb}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item,index) =>{index.toString} } 
        />
      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the NavigationScreenProps

```js
export interface Props extends NavigationScreenProps {}


class MyContainer extends React.Component<Props> {
  ...
   render() {
   ...
   }
  }
```